# Precise numbers in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to use numbers with a precision of hundreds of decimal places.

I know of the `BigInteger` datatype for ints, but `System.Numerics` falls short beyond the decimal.

How can I achieve anything beyond a simple `Decimal`/`Double` precision in vb.net?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does it fall short in? The .Tostring method on the BigInteger only computes the first 50 decimals by design, but that can be taken care of by sending  "R" as format to the ToString-method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BigRational class didn't make the cut for the .NET 4.0 release.  You can [download it here](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782).

Comment: Okay, any way to perform square root functionality?

Comment: No idea, never actually used it.  15 significant digits is more fingers than I have, always has been good enough for me.  If raising to the power of 0.5 does not help then start a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly googled this and it is apparent that .NET can't handle very large numbers natively. But there are strategies to deal with numbers larger than those that can be stored in any of those types.

This article looked particularly interesting: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/Big_Number.aspx and this wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic